# Wordpress Display parent page URL for child page in a shortcode not working

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress Display parent page URL for child page in a shortcode
the problem is I can't manage to show in a simple shortcode

```
    function page_url_shortcode(){
  global $post;
  if ( $post->post_parent ) { 
    echo get_permalink( $post->post_parent );
 } 
}
add_shortcode('title_url','page_url_shortcode');
```

short code  [title_url]

Comment: It is working for me. I have page /page and /page/subpage, the subpage show URL to /page correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortcodes are expected to *return* something, rather than echo the output. As per the docs (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should never produce an
> output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is
> to be used to replace the shortcode.

Change your permalink call to:

`return get_the_permalink($post->post_parent);`